# Finite covolume of uniform lattice in quotient group

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact group, let $N \leq G$ be a (proper) closed normal subgroup and let $\Gamma \leq G$ be a uniform lattice, i.e., a discrete subgroup such that $G/\Gamma$ Is compact.

Suppose that $\Gamma \cap N$ is a uniform lattice in $N$. Then $\pi(\Gamma)$, where $\pi : G \to G/N$ is the natural map, is a uniform lattice in $G/N$.

Question: Is it possible to express the covolume of $\pi(\Gamma)$ in $G/N$ in terms of the covolume of the closed, co-compact subgroup $\Gamma N$ in $G$? More specifically, as
\begin{align}
vol((G/N)/\pi(\Gamma)) = vol(G/(\Gamma N)) \quad \quad \quad \quad (*)
\end{align}

For specific examples (e.g., $G = \mathbb{H}$ Heisenberg group or $G=\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $N = Z(G)$ the center), I have seen $(*)$ in textbooks, but I would be interested in the general case above.

Edit: Preferably, the involved Haar measures should be normalized to satisfy the integral formula
$$
\int_G f(x) dx = \int_{G/N} \int_N f(x n)\; dn\, d(xN), \quad f \in L^1 (G),
$$
but a different normalization that implies $(*)$ would also be of interest.

Comment: How do you normalize the volumes in $G$ and $G/N$?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Thanks. I would assume that Haar measure on $G$ is given. Then measures on $N$ and $G/N$ are normalized to satisfy Weil’s formula.

Comment: What is Weil's formula?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Please see the edit in the question.

Comment: I think that with the normalization  $$dx=dn\,d(xN)$$ given by the integral formula, you will have $$ {\rm vol}(G/\Gamma)={\rm vol}\big( (G/N)/\pi(\Gamma)\big)\cdot{\rm vol}\big(N/( \Gamma\cap N)\big).$$

Comment: You obtain this formula by integrating the constant function $1$.

Comment: Have you checked the answer to your question when $G=\mathbf{R}^2$ and $N$ is a line? For $G=\mathbf{R}^n$ and $N$ a subspace?

Answer (score 2):

As @MikhailBorovoi comments, this should follow from the general characterizing property of iterated integrals (perhaps what is called "Weil's formula") in the question, and computing integrals by integrating the constant function $1$.

Namely, for (closed) subgroups $C\subset B\subset A$ in a topological group $A$, with appropriate assumptions on modular functions, for $f\in C^0_c(A)$, the basic property is
$$
\int_{C\backslash A} f(a)\;da
\;=\;
\int_{B\backslash A}\int_{C\backslash B} f(ba)\;db\;da
$$
In the case at hand, $A=G$, $B=\Gamma\cdot N$, ...

Comment: I agree with your formula, but it is not clear to me how to obtain from this the desired identity: $vol(G /( \Gamma \cdot N)) = vol((G/N) / p(\Gamma)$. Could you please expand?

Comment: @Umath, I'll respond more fully tomorrow... It is surely worthwhile to write this out, rather than give any impression of hand-waving. :)